# jQuery ajax() returning an undefined object in MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a jQuery function as this:

```
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Accounting/Journal/SaveModal",
            data: varData,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            success: function (e) {
                alert(e);
            },

            error: function (e, ex) {
                $("div#divModalBody").modal('toggle');
                alert(ex);
            },

            complete: function (e) {
                $("div#myLoadingDialog").modal('toggle');
                $("div#myModal").modal('toggle');
            }
        });
```

and my **SaveModal** action is :

```
        //#########################  SaveModal (POST)  #########################
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    [Infrastructure.ProjectActionPermission
        (isVisibleJustForProgrammer: false,
        accessType: Models.Enums.AccessTypes.Special,
        keyName: Resources.Strings.ActionsKeys.Save)]
    public virtual System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult SaveModal
        (System.Guid journalheaderid, System.Guid account, System.Guid center1,
        System.Guid center2, System.Guid center3, System.Guid project, string description,
        decimal debit, decimal credit, string number, int quantity, int shamsid, int shamsim, int shamsiy)
    {
        Models.Accounting.JournalDetail oJournalDetail =
            new Models.Accounting.JournalDetail();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // **************************************************
            if ((shamsid != 0) &&
                (shamsim != 0) &&
                (shamsiy != 0))
            {
                oJournalDetail.Date =
                    Dtx.Calendar.Convert.PersionToCivil
                    (shamsiy, shamsim, shamsid);
            }
            // **************************************************

            oJournalDetail.JournalHeaderId = journalheaderid;
            oJournalDetail.AccountId = account;

            if (center1 != System.Guid.Empty)
            {
                oJournalDetail.Center1Id = center1;
            }
            if (center2 != System.Guid.Empty)
            {
                oJournalDetail.Center2Id = center2;
            }
            if (center3 != System.Guid.Empty)
            {
                oJournalDetail.Center3Id = center3;
            }
            if (project != System.Guid.Empty)
            {
                oJournalDetail.ProjectId = project;
            }

            oJournalDetail.RowDescription = description;
            oJournalDetail.Debit = debit;
            oJournalDetail.Credit = credit;
            oJournalDetail.Number = number;
            oJournalDetail.Quantity = quantity;
            oJournalDetail.IsPending = true;

            // **************************************************
            oJournalDetail.SetInsertDateTime
                (Infrastructure.Sessions.AuthenticatedUser.Id);

            oJournalDetail.SetIsActive
                (oJournalDetail.IsActive,
                Infrastructure.Sessions.AuthenticatedUser.Id, Infrastructure.Utility.Now);
            // **************************************************

            UnitOfWork.AccountingUnitOfWork.JournalDetailRepository.Insert(oJournalDetail);

            UnitOfWork.Save();
        }

        // **************************************************
        ViewBag.ShamsiD =
            new System.Web.Mvc.SelectList
                (Dtx.Calendar.Day.Days, "Value", "Text", oJournalDetail.ShamsiD);

        ViewBag.ShamsiM =
            new System.Web.Mvc.SelectList
                (Dtx.Calendar.Month.Months, "Value", "Text", oJournalDetail.ShamsiM);

        ViewBag.ShamsiY =
            new System.Web.Mvc.SelectList
                (Dtx.Calendar.ShamsiAccountingYear.Years, "Value", "Text", oJournalDetail.ShamsiY);
        // **************************************************

        var varJsonResult =
            Json(new { oJournalDetail },
            System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        ViewBag.JournalDetail = oJournalDetail;

        return (varJsonResult);
    }
    //#########################  SaveModal (POST)  #########################
```

but when I run my code after filling form , I expect to see my object but I saw undefined.
I completely confused and I don't know what is my mistake?

What must I do know?

Comment: Debug the javascript check if the `success` event handler runs, and inspect the variable `e`. Debug the c#, check if the action actually runs and returns something.

Comment: On which line of the script does the error occur? Does it hit your controller?

Comment: no error occurs and it goes through success but e is undefined!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but you are messing up code. You should use model instead of passing each fields.

See below code.

```
       public virtual System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult SaveModal
        (System.Guid journalheaderid, System.Guid account, System.Guid center1,
        System.Guid center2, System.Guid center3, System.Guid project, string description,
        decimal debit, decimal credit, string number, int quantity, int shamsid, int shamsim, int shamsiy)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

            }

            var varJsonResult = Json(new { oJournalDetail }, System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            ViewBag.JournalDetail = oJournalDetail;

            return (varJsonResult);
        }
```

There is no meaning using `ModelState.IsValid` since not using Model. Also, you should return json correctly doing like this.

```
return this.Json(oJournalDetail, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Try this to make sure if you avoid undifined object error.

```
return this.Json(new { IsSuccess = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

**I would recommend you to use MODEL. This is what MVC is all about.**

```
    public class YourModel {
        public Guid JournalHeaderId { get; set; }
        public decimal Debit { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveModal(YourModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //do something

            return this.Json(new { IsSuccess = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return this.Json(new { IsSuccess = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**UPDATED**

You have use `JSON.stringify(object);` to map the model.
Example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var object = new Object();
    object.JournalHeaderId = 'yourguidvaluehere';
    object.Debit = '43.00';

    var objectSerialized = JSON.stringify(object);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Accounting/Journal/SaveModal",
        data: objectSerialized
        //
    });
</script>
```

Comment: dear sir, all of your discussions are true , but these are not my problem, if I put a break point in SaveModal on **    return (varJsonResult);** it is an ok json with data in it, but I can not catch it in my jQuery **success function**

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not able to find the URL. Change URL as below and try

```
url: window.location.pathname + '/Accounting/Journal/SaveModal'
```